# Module not found: Can't resolve '@sanity/client' > 1 | import sanityClient from '@sanity/client';

Tags: model, syntax-error, sanity

I am using "npm install -g @sanity/cli
sanity init --coupon javascriptmastery2022" everything is workig well until I want to fetch the data from sanity client it says: ***Module not found: Can't resolve '@sanity/client'

> 1 | import sanityClient from '@sanity/client';
> 2 | import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';*** and have checked the package json file and saw there is no ***'@sanity/client'*** installed there. then I run ***npm install -g @sanity/client*** and npm command works but there is no ***'@sanity/client'*** found in the package json, and the error is still the same

I really appreciate if anyone can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Install `npm i @sanity/client`

I think it should be solve

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it worked, thank you so much, i face another problem with the same project: 'Error: Configuration must contain `projectId` and my code is: import sanityClient from '@sanity/client';
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';
export  const client = sanityClient ({
    projectID: '******',
    dataset: '******',
    apiVersion: '2022-03-10',
    useCdn: true,
    token: NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_TOKEN
});
const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);
export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);

Answer (score 1):

just use --force to install npm package

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled into this error while following the exact same tutorial.

Simply install image-url to your project:

**npm install --save @sanity/image-url**

Answer (score 0):

I got this error recently, I went on sanity doc, to check for @sanity/client, and there you will see the npm install package (npm install -g @sanity/client)

this works as well-------> "npm i @sanity/client"

if this does work, just use "--force" so
" npm i @sanity/client --force ",
and install in the root folder not the sanity_ecommerce folder, also check the package.json in the root folder to see if it is there.